# how to use [disabled] with two options in ionic angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

this is my page.html:

```
<ion-content *ngIf="charged">
```

**Id ordine:** {{order.id_acg}}
    
      Peso articolo(g): 
      
    
    
      Altezza(cm): 
      
    
    
      Larghezza(cm): 
      
      
    
    
      lunghezza(cm):

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let riga of order.righe">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Riga da preparare:<strong>{{riga.idRiga}}</strong> </ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="riga.checked" name="id_riga"  value="option" (click)="onChange(option)"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  
</ion-list>
<ion-button color="success" type="submit" expand="block" [disabled]=" !f.valid && checkedItems.length <1 " >Crea spedizione
</ion-button>
```

`<ion-button color="success" type="submit" expand="block" [disabled]=" !f.valid && checkedItems.length <1 " (* <== do something like that*)> Crea spedizione </ion-button>`

i want the confirm Button enable only if all inputs are compiled and almost one checkbox is checked, i know to do that but separate, not together. thanks y'all!!

UPDATE: This is the form into the  preview ion-content:

```
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onUpdate()" class="ion-text-center ion-margin-bottom ion-margin-top">
<ion-card-title><strong> Id ordine: </strong>{{order.id_acg}}</ion-card-title>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Peso articolo(g): </ion-label>
  <ion-input required type="number" name="peso" [(ngModel)]="order.peso" placeholder="es: 1500"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Altezza(cm): </ion-label>
  <ion-input required type="number" name="altezza" [(ngModel)]="order.altezza" placeholder="es: 0.60"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Larghezza(cm): </ion-label>
  <ion-input required type="number" name="larghezza" [(ngModel)]="order.larghezza" placeholder="es: 0.30">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>lunghezza(cm): </ion-label>
  <ion-input required type="number" name="lunghezza" [(ngModel)]="order.lunghezza" placeholder="es: 0.20">
  </ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-list *ngFor="let riga of order.righe">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>ID Riga da preparare: <strong> {{riga.idRiga}}</strong> </ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="riga.checked" name="id_riga"  value="option" (click)="onChange(option)"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
  
</ion-list>
<ion-button color="success" type="submit" expand="block" [disabled]=" !(f.valid && checkedItems.length > 1)" >Crea spedizione
</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditions like this

for atleast one checkbox is checked

```
[disabled]="!(f.valid && checkedItems.length > 1)"
```

for all the checkboxes need to be checked

```
[disabled]="!(f.valid && checkedItems.length == order.righe.length)"
```

Update the checkbox to this

```
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="riga.checked" name="id_riga"  (ionChange)="onChange()"></ion-checkbox>
```

Update the onChange funtion with this

```
onChange() {
   this.checkedItems = this.order.righe.filter((d: any) => d.checked);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vijay for your tip, but that doesn't work :/.  I show you my  page.ts  method that i call with checkedItems, maybe there is somethink wrong.  `onChange(item) {
    if(this.checkedItems.includes(item)) {
      this.checkedItems = this.checkedItems.filter((value)=>value!=item);
    } else {
      this.checkedItems.push(item)
    }
  }`

Comment: I have updated the answer now according to your code now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake. I meant one or more checkboxes. your solution is gran if i can select only one. thanks a lot for your support

Comment: If you want to check if all the boxes are checked, use [disabled]="!(f.valid && checkedItems.length == this.order.righe.length)", updated the answer for both conditions.

Comment: my checkedItems is `checkedItems =[],`.  so is an "any" type. is that ok? i think the problem maybe is for this variable

Comment: no, not an issue with variable, have you updated the checkbox's (click) to (ionChange)?